# change graph according to slider position

Tags: r

Here is my code. I am trying to make an rshiny page to show the mean symptoms in the past 30 days vesus the state based off of slider position (1 to 12 - for month). I know it is a little sloppy but I almost have it. I can get a graph that changes the title based off of the month on the slider but the graph just lists all of the data and not by month. Any help would be great.

```
  `asthma = read.csv("AsthmaChild.Ozone.2006_2007.Sample.csv")
  state.month = asthma[,-3:-10]
  state.month = state.month[,-4]
  state.month = aggregate(state.month$Symptoms.Past30D ~ state.month$STATE + 
  state.month$Month, state.month, mean)
  colnames(state.month) = c("STATE", "Month", "Symptoms.Past30D")

  sd = asthma[,-3:-10]
  sd = sd[,-4]
  sd = aggregate(sd$Symptoms.Past30D ~ sd$STATE + sd$Month, sd, function(x) 
  sd = sd(x))
  colnames(sd) = c("STATE", "Month", "sd")

  merged = merge(state.month,sd, by=c("STATE", "Month"))

  df = count(asthma, "STATE", "Month")
  colnames(df) = c("STATE","Freq")
  data = merge(df, merged,by=c("STATE"))
  data$sem = (data$sd)/(sqrt(data$Freq))
  merged = data
  merged$ConfUp = (merged$Symptoms.Past30D) + (merged$sem)
  merged$ConfDown = (merged$Symptoms.Past30D) - (merged$sem)


  merged$Month = as.character(merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("12", "December", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("11", "November", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("10", "October", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("9", "September", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("8", "August", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("7", "July", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("6", "June", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("5", "May", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("4", "April", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("3", "March", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("2", "February", merged$Month)
  merged$Month = gsub("1", "January", merged$Month)

  index = c(1:12)
  values = c("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", 
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December")


  ui = fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel( 
     sliderInput("Month", "Month: Jan=1, Dec=12",min = 1, max = 
     12,step=1,value=1)),
     mainPanel(plotOutput("plot")))

  server = function(input,output){


  sliderInput(inputId="Month",
                       label="Month: Jan=1, Dec=12",
                       min = 1,
                       max = 12,
                       value=1,
                       step=1)

           mainPanel(plotOutput("plot"))

  dat = reactive({
   test <- merged[merged$Month %in% 
   seq(from=min(input$Month),to=max(input$Month),by=1),]
    })             

  output$plot = renderPlot({
   ggplot(data=merged, aes(x=Symptoms.Past30D, y = STATE)) +  
   geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=ConfUp,xmax=ConfDown), height=1, linetype = 1) + 
   xlab ("Mean Sympotms.Past30D (SEM)") + ylab ("STATE")  + 
   labs(title=paste(values[match(input$Month, index)]))
   })
   }
   shinyApp(ui, server)`
```

Comment: Without a dummy data for `asthma`, noone can reproduce your app..